# String In XML body with no header

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service with several methods. I would like to log the raw request that came in from the client regardless of how this was sent. I am using the below method

```
public Message CreateMessage(Message message)
     {
       MessageBuffer buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
       var messageCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();
       Console.WriteLine(messageCopy.ToString());
       return buffer.CreateMessage();     
     }
 public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            request = CreateMessage(request);
            return null;

        }
```

I get the XML in result and string in body but with headers I want the string in body but no header at all. Can anybody help me in this regard.

Comment: Can anybody have any suggestion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I sort it out and get the solution to overwrite the Body Writer Class. Please find the detailed solution below.

```
namespace WcfServiceRaw
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract(ReplyAction = "ResponseToGetDataRequest")]
        Message GetData();
    }

}
namespace WcfServiceRaw
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        public Message GetData()
        {
            // Create body
            TestDataWriter body = new TestDataWriter("<test>data</test>");

            // Create messatge
            MessageVersion ver = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageVersion;
            Message msg = Message.CreateMessage(ver, "ResponseToGetDataRequest", body);

            //Debug.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
            return msg;

        }

    }

    class TestDataWriter : BodyWriter
    {
        string _data;

        public TestDataWriter(string data)
            : base(false)
        {
            _data = data;
        }

        protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteRaw(_data);
        }
    }
```

And The Client is:

```
namespace WcfClientRaw
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //IMyContract proxy = ChannelFactory<IMyContract>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(address));
            WcfServiceRaw.Service1Client proxy = new WcfServiceRaw.Service1Client();
            using (proxy as IDisposable)
            {
                Message msg = proxy.GetData();
                Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine();

                XmlDictionaryReader xdr = msg.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
                //string exp = "<test>data</test>";
                string act = xdr.ReadOuterXml();
                //Debug.Assert(exp == act);
                Console.WriteLine(act);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark this as your solution to help others with the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GetReaderAtBodyContents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.getreaderatbodycontents.aspx) on the System.ServiceModel.Channel.Message class.

```
var reader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadOuterXml());
```

Comment: I still get extra tags in body. Actually I am using below mentioned service contract string Greet(string name); and  public string Greet(string name)
        {
            return "Hello ," + name;
        }

Comment: What "extra tags" do you get?

Comment: Actually I am passing raw data from client end and want to write that raw data as it is in the xml body tag but what happened when the raw data passed to service it will write tags like in my code it wrote <s:Body><Greet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><name>Mr.Wasif this is a test App for raw data message exchange. I hope this time we get required result.</name>
</Greet>
</s:Body>  Actually i just need the following data in tag [Mr.Wasif this is a test App for raw data message exchange. I hope this time we get required result.]